# Pivoting a string from a table function in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task to create a table function that receives a string and sorts it into different columns.
The string itself may vary, but the columns are supposed to be the same always.

[image: This is how the result set is supposed to look]

The string is: `'100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3'`, but for example if I add "¬400^Test4" that should be in the result set as well.

Here is what I've managed to do so far.

```sql
if object_id('stringSplit1') is not null
drop function stringSplit1
go

create function stringSplit1(@input varchar(1000))
returns @outputtable table (ord varchar(1000), dta_1 varchar(1000), dta_2 varchar(1000))
as
begin
    
return
end
go


select [1] as dta_1, [2] as dta_2 from (
select row_number() over(partition by id order by (select null)) as rn, value
    from (select value as id from string_split('100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3', '¬')) as bo
        cross apply string_split(id, '^') as bk) t

    pivot(
        max([value]) for [rn] in ([1], [2]) 
            ) as pvt
```

Comment: So, presumably, `^` is your column separator and `¬` your line separator?

Comment: Yes.  It appears so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, although you *can* use `STRING_SPLIT` the order of the value returned by it is **not** guaranteed. As you define the length of your parameter as `1000` in your function `stringSplit1` this means we can safely use a function like [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) which *does* guarantee the order by providing the ordinal position of each value. This means we can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT SSr.ItemNumber AS Ord,
       MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_1,
       MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_2
FROM (VALUES('100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3'))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourColumn,'¬') SSr
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(SSr.Item,'^') SSc
GROUP BY SSr.ItemNumber;
```

If you want this as a functionm, use an **inline** table value function, not a multi-line TVF like you have done:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DatasetSplit (@Input varchar(8000))
RETURNS table AS
RETURN
    SELECT SSr.ItemNumber AS Ord,
           MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_1,
           MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_2
    FROM (VALUES(@Input))V(YourColumn)
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourColumn,'¬') SSr
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(SSr.Item,'^') SSc
    GROUP BY SSr.ItemNumber;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DatasetSplit ('100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3') DS;
```

If you want to parametrise your row and column delimiters, then you could do it like this:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DatasetSplit (@Input varchar(8000), @RowDelimiter char(1), @ColumnDelimiter char(1))
RETURNS table AS
RETURN
    SELECT SSr.ItemNumber AS Ord,
           MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_1,
           MAX(CASE SSc.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN SSc.Item END) AS dta_2
    FROM (VALUES(@Input))V(YourColumn)
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourColumn,@RowDelimiter) SSr
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(SSr.Item,@ColumnDelimiter) SSc
    GROUP BY SSr.ItemNumber;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DatasetSplit ('100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3','¬','^') DS;
```

---

Definition of `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` for completeness:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
 WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot here! <3 I was trying to do this for a few days now

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, in similar cases, a JSON-based approach is also an option. You need to transform the input text into a valid JSON structure (`'100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3'` into `[{"100":"TEst"},{"200":"TEst2"},{"300":"Test3"}]` ) and parse it with `OPENJSON()`. The result from this call is a table with columns `[Key]`, `[Value]` and `[Type]`. When the parsed text is a JSON array, the `[Key]` column holds the index of each element in the JSON array.

UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringSplit1 (@Text varchar(8000))
RETURNS table AS
RETURN
   SELECT 
      (CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) + 1) AS [Ord],
      j2.[key] AS dat_1,
      j2.[value] AS dat_2
   FROM  OPENJSON(CONCAT('[{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(@Text, '¬', '"},{"'), '^', '":"'), '"}]')) j1
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.StringSplit1('100^TEst¬200^TEst2¬300^Test3')
```

Result:

```
Ord dat_1 dat_2
---------------
1   100  TEst
2   200  TEst2
3   300  Test3
```

As an additional note, if you use SQL Server 2017+, you may use `STRING_ESCAPE()` to escape the input text:

```
...
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(
   '[{"', 
   REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@Text, 'json'), '¬', '"},{"'), '^', '":"'),
   '"}]'
)) j1
...
```

Comment: This is really useful, but can i do it with pivot ?

Comment: @AnastasKovachev Why do you need a `PIVOT`? It will make the function more complicated.

Comment: Because I am told to do it with pivot specifically. :(

Comment: @AnastasKovachev You have an elegant solution here (+1).  Your supervisor may not have considered other approaches ... As a developer, you have a moral imperative to  offer other solutions.